# PHP MySQL INSERT and UPDATE from ODBC

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, odbc, sql-insert

I have a MySQL database that makes a connection to a local MS Access database through ODBC.

I currently have the script properly inserting data from the MS Access database to my MySQL database. The problem is that the MS Access database gets updated daily - so I need code to also update my MySQL database.

Here's what I have - and the result is that i get no errors and nothing is updated (however the insert works fine):

```
<?php
$conn=odbc_connect('Prod_Schedule','','');
  if (!$conn) {
    exit("Connection Failed:" . $conn);
  }

  $sql="SELECT `ID`, `WO_NUM`, `WO_LINE`, `SALES_CCN`, `SO`, `SO_LINE`, `SO_DELIVERY`, `MAS_LOC`, `DUE_DATE`, `FGC`, `HPL`, `DESCRIPTION` FROM `Schedule` WHERE `ID` > $refid AND `HPL` <> 'PART' AND LEN(HPL) > 0";
  $rs=odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
    if (!$rs) {
      exit("Error in SQL");
    }

    $todays_date = date('m/d/Y', time());

    while(odbc_fetch_row($rs)){

       $sql = "INSERT INTO `production_schedule` (`ID`, `WO_NUM`, `WO_LINE`, `SALES_CCN`, `SO`, `SO_LINE`, `SO_DELIVERY`, `MAS_LOC`, `DUE_DATE`, `FGC`, `HPL`, `DESCRIPTION`) VALUES (?,    ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?)";

       $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

       for($i=1;$i<=odbc_num_fields($rs);$i++){
         $stmt ->bindValue($i, odbc_result($rs,$i));
       }

       $stmt ->execute(); 

       $sqlup = "UPDATE `production_schedule` 
        SET 
        `ID` = ?, 
        `WO_NUM` = ?, 
        `WO_LINE` = ?, 
        `SALES_CCN` = ?, 
        `SO` = ?, 
        `SO_LINE` = ?, 
        `SO_DELIVERY` = ?, 
        `MAS_LOC` = ?, 
        `DUE_DATE` = ?, 
        `FGC` = ?, 
        `HPL` = ?, 
        `DESCRIPTION` = ?
        WHERE `DUE_DATE` < '$todays_date'";

   for($i=1;$i<=odbc_num_fields($rs);$i++){
      $stmt ->bindValue($i, odbc_result($rs,$i));
   }
   $stmt ->execute(); 

   }

odbc_close($conn);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use PHP `cron` jobs so you can run daily scripts.

[Here](http://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/php/run-php-scripts-from-cron-jobs) is an example.

Comment: The problem is that the script isnt updating. Also, I have to run this from Windows and from what I read you can't run a cron job from windows.

Comment: Cron jobs in windows are called scheduled tasks.